# How to install clang with C++17 on Travis CI?

Tags: c++, travis-ci, c++17, clang++

I'm trying to setup Trevis CI with clang 4.0. I need C++17 support. I use following script:

```
language: cpp
sudo: required

os:
    - linux

compiler:
    - clang

env:
    - TARGET_CPU=x86 BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Debug
    - TARGET_CPU=x86 BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
    - TARGET_CPU=x64 BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Debug
    - TARGET_CPU=x64 BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
    - TARGET_CPU=amd64 BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Debug
    - TARGET_CPU=amd64 BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release

before_install:  
  - sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-4.0 main"
  - sudo apt-get update -qq

install: 
  - sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
  - sudo apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated -qq clang++-4.0
  - export CXX="clang++-4.0"

script:
    - mkdir build
    - cd build
    - cmake .. -DTARGET_CPU=$TARGET_CPU -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$BUILD_CONFIGURATION
    - make
```

Despite of clang 4.0 was successfully installed [build](https://travis-ci.org/vukis/Utilities/jobs/255864466) fails with message: `error: no member named 'make_unique' in namespace 'std'`. It means I have even no C++11 support.
How I can fix it? Did I miss something in `travis.yml`?

Comment: I think clang depends on GCC's standard library implementation, so try installing that and see if that works.

Comment: @Cpp plus 1 I can install GCC7 which support C++17. What you mean: install GCC's std library with Clang compiler?

Comment: I think you might need to install all of GCC and add it to your system's path.

Comment: Hm.. You mean get rid of clang?

Comment: No, I  mean install GCC and Clang.

Answer (score 1):

Your Clang version should be fine, the issue is (based on my experience) Travis not respecting various CMake configurations. For some reason, in my experience, Travis CI seems to ignore the `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` variable in CMake.

For example, Travis will ignore the following lines (for C++11) in my CMakeLists.txt.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CXX_STANDARD TRUE)
```

If I manually add the flags, I can get successful builds:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

For C++17, you would like to change this to `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` and `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++1z")`.

None of this is ideal, IMO, but it's a serviceable workaround.

Comment: I use `add_compile_options("-std=c++1z")`. Just now tried as you wrote but fails again with same error.

Comment: @Viktor, you can explicitly set the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` (not compile_options) and it **should** work. I've been using this on Travis CI for a while. Remember that Clang 4.0 doesn't fully support C++17 yet, but it should have good partial support.
https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html

Comment: @Viktor, I should also add that adding these flags will not remove the default or existing flags for the compiler, since I've explicitly chosen to keep them and just append `-std=c++1z` to the end.

Comment: Thanks. I know regarding append flags. I added `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++1z")` CMakeLsits.txt. But it doesn't work with clang, with g++ is ok.

Comment: I know this is really old, but I'm having a similar problem and the root cause is Travis trying to use an outdated version of g++'s copy of the standard library. Just in case that's a useful pointer in the right direction for anyone.